# use nodejs url dependency in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

Is there a way of using the nodejs **url** dependency in an angular component (service)?
I would like to parse a url object like this:

```
{
 protocol : 'http', 
 host: 'localhost:8000>', 
 pathname: 'api/items'
}
```

into a url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/items'.
I'm familiar with nodejs **url** dependency that has the format method that do this:

```
url.format(
{
   protocol: 'http',
   host:'localhost',
   pathname: '/api/items'
})
```

Comment: Why not simply `url = \`${obj.protocol}://${obj.host}${obj.pathname}\`` ? Why would you need a library for this?

Comment: I'm currently doing so, but I thought of a "cleaner" way to treat when there is a need to treat special characters in various OS.